# atomatic (auto-re-calculate) fill series between 2 variables

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to fill in column **c** series of dates or numbers in range of values in `A1` and `B1`.

Example:

```
    A1             B1             C
17/12/2013     04/12/2013     17/12/2013
                              16/12/2013
                              15/12/2013
                              14/12/2013
                              13/12/2013
                              12/12/2013
                              11/12/2013
                              10/12/2013
                              09/12/2013
                              08/12/2013
                              07/12/2013
                              06/12/2013
                              05/12/2013
                              04/12/2013
```

is there some way to do it? prefer with no VBA if possible.

Comment: If you want a formulaic solution, you'd have to either have a column filled with formulae so that upon change of the date range, the whole column can update, or drag the formulae up or down (this one will update faster due to having less cells to update). Any preference? You still need to answer CharlieRB's questions.

Comment: thanks for response
1. formatted as date, but, can be numbers also, it's same...
2. I need it to keep non relevant(not filled) cells blank. that is the reason I can't use IF THEN "" function.
3. I'm still need the answer. thanks.